# Find general solution of this pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$u_{tt} = u_{xx} +\frac{3}{2}u_{tx} − 4u_{x} + u_{t} − 6{u}$

Suggestion: use $u(x,t)=e^{ax+bt}v(x,t)$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Since you are already  given an ansatz $u\left(x,t\right) = e^{ax+bt} v\left(x,t\right)$, you can just compute partial derivatives and substitute them into equation, i.e.

\begin{alignedat}{5}
u = v \cdot e^{ax+bt} 
&\implies &
u_x &= v \cdot a e^{ax+bt}  + v_x\cdot  e^{ax+bt} 
&& = \left(v_x + av \right)e^{ax+bt} 
\\ &\implies&
u_t &= v \cdot be^{ax+bt}  +  v_{t} \cdot e^{ax+bt}
&& = \left(v_t^\phantom{1} + bv \right)  e^{ax+bt} 
\\ &\implies&
u_{xx} &=\left(v_{xx} + av_{x}\right) e^{ax+bt} +  \left(v_x + av \right) a e^{ax+bt} 
&& = \left(v_{xx} + 2av_{x} + a^2v \right)  e^{ax+bt} 
\\ &\implies&
u_{xt} &=\left(v_{xt} + av_{t}\right) e^{ax+bt} +  \left(v_x + av \right) be^{ax+bt} 
&& = \left(v_{xt} + av_{t} + bv_{x}+ abv \right)  e^{ax+bt} 
\\ &\implies&
u_{tt} &=\left(v_{tt} + bv_{t}\right) e^{ax+bt} +  \left(v_{t} + bv \right) b e^{ax+bt} 
&& = \left(v_{tt} + 2bv_{t} + b^2v \right)  e^{ax+bt} 
\end{alignedat}

Now if you substitute expressions above into equation and simplify algebra, you should get a very nice and solvable equation.
Hope you can proceed on your own from here.

Comment: I did all this, but I could not conclude on the solution

Comment: @amathstudent Why don't you show us your work then so we can try to pinpoint your mistake?

Comment: $v_{tt}- v_{xx} -\frac{3}{2}v_{tx} + (2b- \frac{3}{2}a - 1)v_{t} +(4 - \frac{3}{2}b - 2a)v_{x} + (4a - b - a^2 - \frac{3}{2}ab + 1) v =0$   
I can not get out of this part.

Comment: @amathstudent Are you sure expressions in parenthesis are correct? For example, I do not see the $b^2$ term anywhere, while it must be present.

Comment: @amathstudent 
Also, when you fix your algebra, what are the values of $a$ and $b$ that will make  low order terms disappear?

Comment: help me,please. is it correct? $v_{tt}- v_{xx} -\frac{3}{2}v_{tx} + (2b- \frac{3}{2}a - 1)v_{t} +(4 - \frac{3}{2}b - 2a)v_{x} + (4a - b+b^2 - a^2 - \frac{3}{2}ab + 6) v =0$